# Magento 2 Installation Bug

Tags: magento2, database, server-setup, hosting

Hello I have moved magento2 on live server that centos6 server, And my root directory is /var/www/html/magento source code. But my problem is my backend side working but frontend side just loaded.

How can i resolved ?

Url is : http://204.232.133.184/

Comment: Your url given is not loading, if  possible add a screen shot with error.

Comment: My homepage is just loaded nothing to display.